# Rate of heat exchange based on volume of water

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment

Suppose I have two Water-Bucket with same size. 
First bucket is half filled with water having temperature of the 100°C and second bucket is fully filled with water having temperature of 50°C.

If the room temperature is 20°C then the temperature of water of which bucket will falldown to room temperature first and why???

I know it may be a silly/simple question, but I really want to understand one real life situation.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think the first bucket's temperature will fall down first because the temperature difference is high for it.

Comment: When the first bucket gets down to 50 C, what temperature do you think the second bucket temperature will be down to?  Do you think the first bucket will ever catch up?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat more interesting than I originally thought it would be.

Using Newtons Law of Cooling for [Temperature as a Function of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling#Temperature_function-of-time_solution_in_terms_of_object_heat_capacity) we have the equation $$\Delta T (t) = \Delta T (0) e^{-bt}$$
Where $\Delta T = T(t) - T_{room}$, $T(0) = Initial \ Temperature$, $b = \frac{hA}{mc_p}$ and $t$ is time.

First let's compare $b$ for these two scenarios.  We will assume the heat transfer coefficient $h$ is the same for both (same buckets, same air, same objects etc.).  We also know $c_p$ is approximately the same in both conditions.  You can then see that the half full bucket will obviously have half the mass of the full bucket.  From now on the subscript 100 will represent the 100°C situation, and subscript 50 will represent the 50°C situation.

There is twice as much water in the second situation so $m_{50} = 2m_{100}$.

We also know the areas of heat transfer will be different (due to the volume).  Assuming the bucket is a perfect cylinder (just an approximation) the area is $$A = 2 \pi r^2 + \pi r h$$  And we know the 50°C water should take approximately twice the volume of the 100°C water because there is twice as much.  Since you said it's half full, I'll assume that the height of the 100°C water is half the height of the 50°C water.  The ratio $\frac{A_{50}}{A_{100}}$ depends on the values of h and r.  When $h \approx r$ then $\frac{A_{50}}{A_{100}} \approx \frac43$.  When $h \gt\gt r$ then $\frac{A_{50}}{A_{100}} \approx 2$.

So we have our equations and relations, now we need to solve.  Taking the natural logarithm of both sides for the $\Delta T(t)$ equation gives us something we can work with.  $$\ln (\Delta T(t)) = \ln (\Delta T(0)) -  bt$$

Note: It will take infinite time for both to truly reach room temperature.  Instead use 21°C as final temp so $\Delta T(t) = 1$.

You'll notice we have two possible values for $b$ based on the radius and height of the bucket.  When $h \approx r$ we get $\frac{b_{50}}{b_{100}} \approx \frac 46$ and when $h \gt \gt r$ we get $\frac{b_{50}}{b_{100}} \approx 1$ so either $b_{100} \approx b_{50}$ or $\frac 46 b_{100} \approx b_{50}$.

Subbing values into the final equation for 100°C : $$\ln (1) = \ln (100 - 20) - b_{100}t$$ rearranging: $$\frac{\ln (1) - \ln (80) }{-b_{100}} = t{100}$$ and for the 50°C one $$\ln (1) = \ln (50 - 20) - b_{50}t$$ rearranging: $$\frac{\ln (1) - \ln (30) }{-b_{50}} = t_{50}$$

Substituting in some values: $$\frac {-4.382}{-b_{100}} = t_{100}$$ and $$\frac {-3.401}{-b_{50}} = t_{50}$$ to compare when $h \gt \gt r$ we get $$t_{100} = 1.421 t_{50}$$ and when $h \approx r$ $$t_{100} = 2.132 t_{50}$$

To summarize, it should take between 1.4 and 2x as long to cool the 100°C bucket.  I figured I'd do the math because I wasn't sure how the parameters would all interact.

Comment: Thank you for such descriptive answer but I have doubt regarding  (b100/b50)≈(4/6). Based on your description, I have calculated the value of (b100/b50) and It is (8/3).  Can you please check it? Because if it is true than final answer should be t50 = 2.065 * t100 .

Comment: @rohitgupta Good catch, though that wasn't the actual problem.   At some point going between some paper scrap calculations I did and here I decided to mix up how I wrote the area fractions.  None of the final value change, just a few of the fractions I wrote.